# SQL queries to MSSQL contains pauses even with MARS enabled

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, jdbc, jtds

We are testing JDBC drivers from jTDS and Microsoft, and we are suffering from unwanted pauses in query execution. Our application opens many ResultSets and fetches only a few rows from each. Each query selects about 100k rows, but we fetch only about 50 (which is enough to fill a page). The problem is that every query after the first contains a pause of about 2s, on which the driver loads all rows from the previous ResultSet to a temporary storage (memory or disk), so they can be traversed later. Because we have about 6 queries in worst scenarios, there will be a pause of about 10s, which makes the application unresponsive to the user. MSSQL version is 2005.

To remove such pauses, we've tried to enable MARS (Multiple Active Result Sets) via connection string parameters of Microsoft JDBC driver (due to lack of documentation, we tried everything that is listed on https://sites.google.com/site/sqlconnect/sql2005strings). Example of connection string:

jdbc:sqlserver://TESTDBMACHINE;instanceName=S2005;databaseName=SampleDB;MarsConn=yes

But none of them solves the problem. Microsoft JDBC driver seems to accept anything at connection string - if you replace MarsConn=yes by PleaseBeFast=yes, MS driver ignores the parameter and doesn't even log the fact. I don't know if MARS is a client-only feature that just caches rows from a previously active result set, or if it's a server feature. I don't even know how to detect, from the server side, if a given connection is using MARS. If you can comment on this, it will be welcome.

Another solution for the pause was to use scrollable (bidirectional) result sets. This removes the pause, but makes fetch time 80% slower and more network consuming. We are now considering to implement a JDBC connection wrapper that keeps a pool of actual connections and automatically issue queries to distinct "ResultSet free" connections. But this is somewhat cumbersome because we need to keep a link between each connection and its active ResultSet. Also it would consume more connections from the server and may cause troubles to DBAs. And this solution doesn't help if there is an active transaction, on which all queries must be issued on the same connection.

Do you know some parameter, configuration, specific API, link or trick that can remove the pause from the second and subsequent query executions?

Comment: Why don't you implement paging inside of SQL Server, instead of having your app do that? There is no reason to return 100K rows if you're only going to show 50. You're quite lucky the delay is only 2s.

Comment: Actually, the user may PAGE DOWN and see more. It can even type END and fetch the entire 100k rows. If we really needed only 50 rows, we would simply close the ResultSet just after fetching that 50 rows and problem would be solved. But we can't predict user behavior, and some queries are very complex, so they are slow for initial execution and it's hard for us to add filters to select only partial results. Using TOP works for the first page, but what about the others?

Comment: What most sites do is submit a request for the next 50 rows (this is what I meant by paging). I doubt Google returns all 37,000,000 results when you run a search, and shows you 10 at a time without ever going back to the server... the cost of getting those 50 rows is outweighed by the waste of returning all 100K probably for 99.9% of your users. Please read this SSC article: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/66030/ and all the follow-up comments: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic672980-329-1.aspx

Comment: you should post one of your queries with table definitions and see if someone here can add the paging into it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We've created an ODBC data source using the SQL Server driver (Native Client 10 - sqlncli10.dll). This ODBC data source was configured to enable MARS (key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ datasource`, value of `MARS_Connection` must be `Yes`). Then we used Sun's JDBC-ODBC bridge, and voilá! The pauses were gone, and surprisingly, fetch time became faster than JTDS and MSSQL pure Java JDBC drivers!

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345109(SQL.90).aspx, MARS is a server-aided feature. The pure Java drivers (from JTDS and MSSQL) doesn't seem to support served-based MARS (at least we couldn't enable it after many configuration changes). Because most of our user base that uses MSSQL Server runs on Windows (no surprise), we are about to make the switch from JTDS to JDBC-ODBC. Both Native Client ODBC driver and JDBC-ODBC bridge seems to be mature, full featured and up-to-date solutions, so I guess there should be no problems. If you know some, please comment!

Linux based users will still use JTDS. Since now we know that MARS is a server-aided feature, we'll fill a feature request for JTDS and Microsoft to support MARS in their pure Java JDBC drivers.

Comment: Don't know the reason for the down vote. I'm aware that this might not the best solution from a technical point of view, but changing hundreds of SQL queries of a 10+ years old architecture would take months and might bring quality problems. With this solution, the few customers that are experiencing issues will be satisfied, and some others will see improvements in performance. For this reason, I'm sure this is the best solution from a business point of view.

Also, I couldn't find anywhere else how to enable MARS in a JDBC connection. That's the main reason for which I've answered.

Answer (score 1):

**fix your SQL queries!**  why only use the first 50 or so from 100k rows?? use `TOP 100` or something like that!  There is no reason that the application should be filtering 100k rows, that is the job of the database.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not an option! Some queries are very complex and they take up to 3s just to execute the query plan, and we can't afford to execute it again every time the user presses PAGE DOWN. The GUI that issues queries is generic - it doesn't know whether the queries are simple or complex, or if they return 10 or 10k rows. This app works fine on Oracle, DB/2 and Informix. Only MSSQL has this pauses.

Comment: I'm confused.  you say `but we fetch only about 50 (which is enough to fill a page)` in the question, yet in your comment you say `we can't afford to execute it again every time the user presses PAGE DOWN` so where do you get the data for page two? you only fetched a page worth.

Comment: The ResultSet is kept open. When the user PAGE DOWN, we simple issue next() until page two is filled. This is a client application.

Comment: So you keep 100K rows "open" just in case the user pages down and is interested in something beyond the first 50 rows? Again, other sites solve this by fixing their queries, improving their indexing, caching / replicating, encouraging narrower searches, etc. ... not expecting magic pixie dust to make MARS solve the problem. :-)

Comment: This is not a website with a million users connected to a portal or something. It's just a client/server application used mostly by 20 users, or 100 users in the greatest companies. I didn't tell it's a good solution - it's a solution that works for most of our 9k customers (each with its own database installation) and other databases like Oracle, DB/2 and even a few Informix.

Comment: I have **never ever** seen any application (web, desktop, etc) in my 20+ years pause/put on hold a database activity waiting for user interaction.

Comment: KM and Aaron, thanks for your comments. I will transmit your perceptions to our team. Perhaps this can change our minds and evolve our 10-year old architecture. I was hoping for a quick solution - a hidden parameter or specific API, but I guess there will be none. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Far more important that your client woes is what happens on the server side. Since you issue queries and then you stop reading the result the server will have to suspend the query in the middle of the execution because the network buffers are full and has no room to write the result into. A query suspended in the middle of the execution is consuming  a *lot* of resources: memory, locks and, most importantly, a worker thread (there are [*very* few](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187024.aspx) of these lying around).

Issue queries for only the data you need, consume all the data, free the connection and, more importantly, the server resources. If your queries are to complex, go back to the drawing board and redesign your data model to properly answer, efficiently, the queries your requesting from it. Right now you are totally barking up the wrong tree, you're simply asking how to make a bad situation worse.